# Migration to stats.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Today I came across [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136199/em-algorithm-for-mixture-of-power-and-gaussian-distributions), which seems to me would be better asked at [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com). I  tried flagging the question as off-topic/migration, but only [meta.mathoverflow.net](http://meta.mathoverflow.net) and [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) are offered as options. I left a comment to that effect on the question, but I think it would be better if we could select [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) as a possible migration choice.

Comment: Related: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/141/what-outgoing-migration-paths-should-we-have

Comment: Instead, or in addition, to leaving a comment you should likely flag for moderator attention. They are the only ones that can migrate to sites other then the two you mentioned (but they can); so they need to know about the question.

Comment: @quid: I did that too.

Comment: We're still waiting for a response from the moderators at stats.se.

Comment: (Ah, sorry, I'd already migrated it, having forgotten or never known we were asking the stats moderators...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I already set this up earlier today, so... enjoy!

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Can we get the TeX site too?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcía-Raboso There haven't been any migrations to TeX yet at all. Do you have any examples handy of questions that could/should have been migrated there?

Comment: I don't, but the issue has been raised before, specifically in the comments to the top answer to this question: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/141/what-outgoing-migration-paths-should-we-have

Comment: @AlbertoGarcía-Raboso: remember we only get **4** sites. I would think that cstheory or physics or computational science are all more likely to be needed than TeX. We really shouldn't rush to choose the others until the Mods notice a large number of migration requests to a certain SE site.

Comment: @WillieWong: I didn't know we only got four... Does meta.MO count?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcía-Raboso: see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/163/3948 The four does not include our own meta.