# Recommending to move the question to another site

Tags: feature-request, migration

I am trying to recommend to move the question to another SE site.
When I press the corresponding button, the menu pops up which offers me choices:
meta, MathSE, stats. And no more choices. How can I recommend to move it to physicsSE?

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention, and leave a corresponding comment.

Comment: Though as this post is tagged as feature request -- the implementation of which feature do you propose?

Comment: Some related older posts: [What outgoing migration paths should we have?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141) (And specifically for Physics Stack Exchange, also [Migration site list lacks entries](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3486) and [Migration to Physics.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3428).) Some basic info on migration is available [in the tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/migration/info).

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: I propose to extend the list of SE sites to which we can recommend migration.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: From your links I conclude that I am not alone who experiences this problem, but I do not understand why it cannot be solved.