# Migration of questions to cs.SE?

Tags: feature-request

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249227/) just got closed as off-topic. As someone else had already commented there, it is really a computer-science question and thus clearly belongs at cs.stackexchange.com. But we currently don't have an option for CS in the close-vote menu (the only options are math.SE, stats.SE and MO meta). Since this is a situation which is likely to come up fairly often, should this maybe be added to the menu?

Comment: There is discussion on http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/141/what-outgoing-migration-paths-should-we-have . Note that (1) there are two computer science sites (cs and cstheory, the latter aimed at research level), and (2) migration paths are an extremely limited resource, there being only 4 slots available.

Comment: Also: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/572/option-to-migrate-to-cs-theory

Comment: I just migrated it to Computer Science.

Comment: So, in general, you would flag a moderator to get it migrated elsewhere.