# Ability to flag for migration to other stackoverflow sites

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

Currently on mathoverflow, flags can be set for questions to be migrated to meta.mathoverflow, math.stackexchange, and stats.stackexchange. However, there are often questions that belong on other stackexchange sites, such as cstheory.stackexchange, cs.stackexchange, scicomp.stackexchange, or hsm.stackexchange. Is there any chance of expanding that option (perhaps by including a "should be moved to another site, designate the other site below" box)?

Comment: See also: [What outgoing migration paths should we have?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141) You can find a few related discussions among the posts [linked there](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/141) and among other questions tagged ([meta-tag:migration]).

Comment: I'll add that [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) is out of question, since migration paths to beta sites are not allowed. It is possible to have at most four migration past, five if you also count meta. Other than meta, currently [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) are offered in that dialog.

Comment: Since you have mentioned some sites related to computer science, I'll add some previous discussions about those: [Option to migrate to CS Theory](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/572) and [Migration of questions to cs.SE?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2984) Of course, things might have changed since that. Perhaps somebody with sufficient reputation can check [the migration stats](https://mathoverflow.net/tools?tab=migrated) for the sites you mentioned.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: According to the migration statistics, in the last 90 days, 39 questions have been migrated to math.se, six to stats.se, two to scicomp.se and one each to mo-meta, to dsp.se and to hsm.se. This suggests that migration to targets other than math.se and stats.se happens pretty rarely, and can well be done via flags for moderator attention.