# When voting to close, only 3 alternative SE listed as options

Tags: feature-request, migration

If I vote to close, one of the options presented to me is that the question belongs on a different SE site.  I don't recall seeing this option before so I assume this is a relatively new feature, which I think is a good one.  However, only three options are listed (meta.MO, math.SE, and stats.SE).  But I can think of at least three other sites that arise frequently (hsm.SE, cs.SE and cstheory.SE) and there are probably others (physics.SE?).  Why is the list so short?  Can it be lengthened?

Comment: Some related discussions on this meta: [What outgoing migration paths should we have?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141), [Ability to flag for migration to other stackoverflow sites](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3849), [Option to migrate to CS Theory](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/572),  [Migration of questions to cs.SE?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2984), [Migration to Physics.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3428), [Migration site list lacks entries](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3486).

Comment: Since you have mentioned [hsm.se], probably it is worth adding that migrations to that site were seen rather unfavorably by some users: [Why was "The origin(s) of the word “elliptic” migrated to hsm?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4566)  (Some time ago you have posted a related question here: [Is there a consensus on whether history of mathematics questions are acceptable on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/394))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's the generic answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path)

Additional paths can only be added by SE employees, and they'll only do it when there's already enough questions being migrated and the other site is accepting a high proportion of those migrations. In the meantime you can [flag for moderator attention and suggest that they migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148869/how-do-i-request-migration-of-a-question-from-site-x-to-site-y). If this is successful often enough we could request a new path be added (up to 4 plus meta).

Comment: I will add that the [users with 10k+ reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools) have access to [various stats about migrations](https://mathoverflow.net/tools/posts/migrated/stats)

Comment: How can other questions be migrated if we can't vote to migrate them?  Is there some separate procedure for doing so, perhaps only in the reach of high-rep users, or does it have to be initiated by the asker themselves?

Comment: Moderators can do it.  If you are not a moderator you can flag for moderator attention if you think migration is appropriate.