# Migration site list lacks entries

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

The question [What is the integral of temperature over space called?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286985/41291) obviously belongs elsewhere. Most probably the proper place is physics.SE, but in any case not here on meta, not on math.SE, and not stats.SE (it could be accepted there but still there are better choices).

So when proposing to close it as off-topic I do not have correct choice. I realize that the off-topic list cannot be too long, but still I believe at least physics.SE could be there since cases as this must be not that exceptional.

**In few minutes**

Although this was not on the **Related** list, browsing through recent questions I discovered [Migration to Physics.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3428/41291); practically this one is a duplicate of it, but let me still leave mine here as it contains another obvious example.

**In few more minutes**

Following further links, also found [Adding "Academia.StackExchange" to the migration list](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2214/41291); a proposal to add academia.SE has been declined, and an answer there explains that the general policy is to severely restrict default migrations since mutual contention of sites is involved. I think I will still leave my question open for consideration.

Comment: It seems that this question discusses migration paths in general: [What outgoing migration paths should we have?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141) Her are two more posts about specific sites where you can also find more details: [Stack Overflow Reference in Out of topic flag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2860) and  [Option to migrate to CS Theory](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/572).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for providing highly relevant information as usual. In principle it is now clear that my question is superseded by several others, but I still would like to leave it open as additional evidence for extending that list with (at least) physics.SE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migration to Physics.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3428/migration-to-physics-se)