# Redirection for off-topics posts

Tags: discussion, migration

At the moment there are three choices in the Closing > Off-Topics > Migration tab.

Shouldn't the other stackexchange websites 
http://matheducators.stackexchange.com and https://hsm.stackexchange.com/
be added to the list?

Comment: The sites you mention are still in beta. According to [this answer](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/141/what-outgoing-migration-paths-should-we-have/163#163) only graduated sites can be used as migration paths.

Comment: To my knowledge there is only a very limited number of open slots for further migration targets available in the dialog box you refer to. But more choices don't seem necessary as in the last 90 days there were only 9 questions which have been migrated from MO to sites other than math.SE -- cf. https://mathoverflow.net/tools/posts/migrated/stats.

Comment: @Kohl I don't have enough rep to access the SE tools. My question is triggered by the following [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256290/appropriate-journal-for-an-article-on-practical-mathematical-teaching).

Comment: In a case like this you can always flag for moderator attention. -- Moderators can migrate questions to any SE site.